# How to Compare PD Julian date with (Current Julian date-7) using JCL- SYNCSORT?

Tags: mainframe, syncsort

I have a requirement as below.

In my input file, I have a packed-decimal Julian date starting in the 23rd position (position 23, length 4).

1. If my the input Julian date is less than (Current Julian date - 7 days) then write the records into output File1.
2. Else write the records into outut File2.

Can anybody let me know the solution for this requirement in SyncSort only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this...

```
//SYSIN  DD *
 SORT FIELDS=COPY,
 OUTFIL FNAMES=01,
 INCLUDE=(23,4,PD,EQ,DATE3P-7)
 OUTFIL FNAMES=02,SAVE
```

DATE3P gives the current date in P'YYYYDDD' packed-decimal format.

Comment: Hi, DATE3P contains wrong date value. it contains 7995548 after converting it. because of this I am not getting right output. Please let me know the packed decimal current date???

Comment: Apart from the typo for OUTFILF, this looks fine to me. Having said that, it is always, to me, "bad" to use the run-date for any data selection, as you will get different results if you happen to run after midnight vs before midnight, re-runs etc.

Comment: @Sekhar are your records variable in length? Did you add four (for the RDW of the variable-length record) to your start position of the date?